# тип float в бинарный вид C++

Tags: c++

Задача из универа:
Для числа типа float при выводе на экран его битового представления указать знаковый бит, порядок и мантиссу. Число вводят с клавиатуры.

Единственное до чего допер:

```
for (int k = 31; k > -1; k--) {
        if (var&(1 << k)) {
            cout << '1';
            }
        else cout << '0';
    }
```

где `var` это само число. Это представление числа в бинарном виде. Косяк в том что только целого типа чисел, так как бинарные операции с `float` не работают.

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом я могу получить бинарное представление числа типа `float`, будем считать что показать мантиссу порядок и знак,  я сам справлюсь

Comment: `float v=1.0;  long var = *(long*)&v;` и посмотреть разрядность float по справочнику.

Comment: Попробуйте рассматривать его как массив `unsigned char`. Типа     `float f = 3.14f;
    unsigned char * x = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&f);` Правда, тут, скорее всего, начнутся разговоры о strict aliasing, но это - *imho, не более* - горние выси стандарта, а практика такое испытание выдержит :)

Comment: Честно, говоря @Harry я такую конструкцию первый раз в жизни вижу , мы еще такое не проходили

Comment: Тогда вам подсказка: читайте методичку. Любое отклонение от методички - препод нагрузит.

Comment: @nick_n_a: Переинтерпретация как `long` - нарушение strict aliasing. Неработоспособно ни в С, ни в С++.

Comment: Пока еще gcc 7.3.0 спокойно воспринимает вот такое `float f = 2.87; long *pl = (long *)&f; printf("f = %f pl = %llx\n", 
  f, *pl & ((1ULL << (sizeof(f) * 8)) - 1));` (да, g++ тоже ест)

Comment: @avp: Воспринимает-то может и спокойно (обычно дает предупреждение), но поведение не определено. И когда и где это неопределенное поведение проявится - предсказать сложно. Strict aliasing означает, что компилятор не видит информационной зависимости между значением `f` и значением `*pl`. Занесение значения `2.87` в `f` может быть отложено и `*pl` будет видеть мусор в памяти.

Comment: @AnT, ну что вы гадаете, до какой степени идиотизма в GNU соблюдают стандарт? Скомпилируйте с -S и посмотрите что получается.

Comment: @ДядяФея, а правильно эту задачу надо делать через `union {float f; uint32_t d;}`

Comment: @avp: Не понимаю, какой смысл разглядывать `-S` одного отдельно взятого примера? Сегодня у него одно `-S`, завтра - другое. Одно невинное изменение в коде или в настройках - и все полетело в тартатары. Гадать о "степени идиотизма" нет необходимости - хорошо известно на что способен GCC в рамках strict aliasing оптимизаций. "Делать через union" будет правильно в С. В С++ этот способ легальным не является.

Comment: @AnT, а вы случайно не в курсе истории появления strict aliasing? Т.е. какой "жизненно важный" код не удавалось достаточно оптимизировать без введения (еще в C99?) этого понятия?

Comment: @avp: Ну вообще-то возможность (или невозможность) компилятора понимать текущую картину aliasing - это одна из основных тяжелых преград на пути оптимизации кода. Тут каждый бит знания способен принести пользу. А уж в каком коде... Компилятор это заботить не должно. Является ли код "жизненно важным" или нет известно только пользователю, а компилятор должен воспринимать любой код, как "жизненно важный".

Comment: @AnT, я имел в виду именно конкретную историю, которая толкнула разработчиков компиляторов в сторону strict aliasing и они не оставили только атрибут restrict. Попробовал что-то найти, но пока из интересного только жалобы от Линуса  еще из 2003-го

Comment: "I tried to get a sane way a few years ago, and the gcc developers really
didn't care about the real world in this area. I'd be surprised if that
had changed, judging by the replies I have already seen.

I'm not going to bother to fight it. 

   Linus"

Answer (score 1):

В языке С++ у вас есть две возможности рассмотреть бинарное представление объекта

1. Переинтерпретировать его как массив `unsigned char[]` соответствующего размера.
2. Скопировать его в самостоятельный массив `unsigned char[]` соответствующего размера при помощи `std::memcpy`.

Также, на большинстве традиционных платформ вы еще можете скопировать его через `std::memcpy` в объект целочисленного типа соответствующего размера, при условии, что данный целочисленный тип не имеет битов-заполнителей (padding bits) и запрещенных представлений (trap representations).

Способ с переинтерпретацей через `union` формально не является легальным в С++ (он разрешен только в С), но на практике скорее всего сработает и он.

Выбирайте, что вам больше нравится.

Answer (score 1):

Воплощаем на практике первый способ из ответа @AnT:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float x = 3.14;

    for (int i = sizeof(x)-1; i >= 0; i--)
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x)[i]);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

(Такой порядок обхода - для little-endian платформ. Для big endian - в обратную сторону.)